# Which takes priority: logback.xml or logback-test.xml?

Tags: xml, logging, logback

I am very new to logback. If my spring boot project contains both the files -

- `logback.xml`: present under *src/main/resources/
- `logback-test.xml`: present under *src/test/resources/

Which one will load? `logback.xml` or `logback-test.xml`?

I was reading the documentation of logback and it says, first it looks for `logback-test.xml` and then `logback.xml`.

So is it like `logback-test.xml` file will take a priority over `logback.xml` if we deploy the application?

Thanks!

Saurabh

Answer (score 54, accepted):

From [the docs](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html):

> Let us begin by discussing the initialization steps that logback follows to try to configure itself:
>
> 1. Logback tries to find a file called logback-test.xml in the classpath.
> 2. If no such file is found, logback tries to find a file called logback.groovy in the classpath.
> 3. If no such file is found, it checks for the file logback.xml in the classpath..
> 4. If no such file is found, service-provider loading facility (introduced in JDK 1.6) is used to resolve the implementation of com.qos.logback.classic.spi.Configurator interface by looking up the file META-INF\services\ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.Configurator in the class path. Its contents should specify the fully qualified class name of the desired Configurator implementation.
> 5. If none of the above succeeds, logback configures itself automatically using the BasicConfigurator which will cause logging output to be directed to the console.
>
> The last step is meant as last-ditch effort to provide a default (but very basic) logging functionality in the absence of a configuration file.

So, the answer to this question ...

> Which takes priority: logback.xml or logback-test.xml?

... is **logback-test.xml**.

However, this question ...

> So is it like logback-test.xml file will take a priority over logback.xml if we deploy the application?

... slightly complicates matters. If you **deploy** both `logback-test.xml` and `logback.xml` then `logback-test.xml` wil take priority but it is not common to deploy `logback-test.xml`. Indeed, given the locations supplied in your question `logback-test.xml` will not, by default, be deployed since it is in the test tree (`src/test/resources`).

Again, from [the docs](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html):

> If you are using Maven and if you place the logback-test.xml under the src/test/resources folder, Maven will ensure that it won't be included in the artifact produced. Thus, you can use a different configuration file, namely logback-test.xml during testing, and another file, namely, logback.xml, in production.

So, in summary; by default `logback-test.xml` will not be deployed so `logback.xml` will be used in your deployed system but `logback-test.xml` will take priority over `logback.xml` when running your test cases.

Comment: If the application is run from the IDE, which configuration is used?

Comment: @glytching: My logback-text.xml is not able to pick up the application.yml entries from src/test/resources. Any idea why? The entries are as below. These entries are being fetched from application.yml in test/resources. But getting UNDEFINED. Am I reading the right classpath

<property resource="application-default.yml" />
 <springProperty scope="context" name="max_log_file_size"
  source="max_log_size" />
 <springProperty scope="context" name="base_log_path"
  source="base_log" />